# How to check if all value in select option are the same with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if I have html like this.

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control" id="catalogsearch_specification2">

<option value="B-3-7">aaa</option>
<option value="B-3-7">bbb</option>
<option value="B-3-7">ccc</option>
<option value="B-3-7">ddd</option>

</select>
```

How to check if all value in select option are the same with javascript ?

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own or any research?

Comment: Why? Whats the usecase doing this on client side? Its a server problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
var isSame = true,
    prev = '';

$('#catalogsearch_specification2 > option').each(function() {
  if (prev && prev !== this.value) {
    isSame = false;
    return;
  }
  
  prev = this.value;
});

console.log(isSame);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" class="form-control" id="catalogsearch_specification2">
  <option value="B-3-7">aaa</option>
  <option value="B-3-7">bbb</option>
  <option value="B-3-7">ccc</option>
  <option value="B-3-7">ddd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'd put a `return;` in the `if` statement to end execution of the `each` loop after the first miss. Upvoted regardless though.

Comment: Thank for your help

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the comment.. Totally agree!

Comment: @YosvelQuintero It will give true if duplicates are there ? Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wa9sezz/) once.

Comment: OP: "check if all value in select option are the same". In your feedle all values are not the same, and than the variable `isSame` is equal to `false`

Answer (score 3):

Use `Set` object to check if each of the `option` elements has the same `value` property. If so - use `Array#forEach` to apply `selected` prop on each of them.

```js
let parent = document.getElementById('catalogsearch_specification2'),
    values = Array.from(parent.children).map(v => v.value);
    
    [...new Set(values)].length == 1 ? Array.from(parent.children).forEach(v => v.selected = true) : null;
```

```html
<select multiple="" class="form-control" id="catalogsearch_specification2">
  <option value="B-3-7">aaa</option>
  <option value="B-3-7">bbb</option>
  <option value="B-3-7">ccc</option>
  <option value="B-3-7">ddd</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This snippet will help you understand how to retrieve values from child nodes.**

```js
var obj = {};
var i = 0
$("#catalogsearch_specification2 option").each(function() {
  //You can write you logic here.
  
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(this.value)) {
    obj[this.value] = {"value" : this.value, "duplicate" : 1};
  } else {
    obj[this.value].duplicate = (obj[this.value].duplicate) + 1;
  }
  
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" class="form-control" id="catalogsearch_specification2">

<option value="B-3-7">aaa</option>
<option value="B-3-7">bbb</option>
<option value="B-3-7">ccc</option>
<option value="B-3-7">ddd</option>

</select>
```

Here I'm taking all the child option element of id "catalogsearch_specification2".

Comment: But this isn't **"checking"** anything it is? So this doesn't really answer the question, this just shows the first step that could be taken before comparing the values for duplicates....

Comment: All this does it show you each value. It doesn't perform any logic to determine if all elements have the same value. This answers nothing

Comment: @NewToJS   I wanted him to write that logic, but if you insist , there you go. Check the edit.

Comment: @Shubham It isn't what I insist.... the point of answering/posting solutions is to actually answer the question, in this case the question is *"How to check if all value in select option are the same with javascript?*" Please note **How to check** not "how to get"

Answer (score 0):

There are a numerous way you can check. Here is a solution. Take the first option value and count total no of option with that value. And again count the total option value. If the count are same then all option values are same otherwise not.

```js
$(function(){
    var firstValue = $('#catalogsearch_specification2').find("option:first-child").val();
    if($('#catalogsearch_specification2 option[value="'+firstValue+'"]').length == $('#catalogsearch_specification2 option').length){
        console.log("All values are same");
    }else{
        console.log("All values are not same");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" class="form-control" id="catalogsearch_specification2">

<option value="B-3-7">aaa</option>
<option value="B-3-7">bbb</option>
<option value="B-3-7">ccc</option>
<option value="B-3-1">ddd</option>

</select>
```